# How to delete first line in the XML from the RSS feed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, rss

I would like to create RSS for my favourite website, but the problem is that it's RSS XML contains first line which corrupts whole RSS when parsing. How to delete the first line of the read data?

I get this error:

> System does not support 'ISO-8859-2' encoding. Line 1, position 31.

Code:

```
void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
      SyndicationFeed feed;
      try {
           using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result)) { 
               // I WOULD LIKE to delete some rows from the Result
               feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
               lista.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
            }
       } catch (WebException we) { 
            MessageBox.Show("The internet connection is down.");
       }
}
```

Comment: is the first line the xml declaration? maybe is a parser problem, I usually parse rss with python BeautifulSoup parser and java Jsoup and never had a problem with xml declaration tag

Comment: The encoding problem is there any other standard NET parser(no need to download)

Comment: oh so it's an encoding issue, I thought the parser doesn't digest the xml declaration...lol, may I ask a link to the rss?

Comment: @user1527232 Sure. Thank You. http://www.mtbnews.pl/component/option,com_rss/feed,RSS2.0/no_html,1/

Comment: you could try to replace "ISO-8859-2" with a more standard "UTF-8" and then give it to the parser and see what happens, the replace in javascript would be newXml = oldXml.replace("ISO-8859-2","UTF-8")  in c# sharp I have no idea, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try using: reader.MoveToContent() or reader.Skip() to skip irrelevant markup at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Tried but I still get exception(look at the main post).

Comment: Thank you for help. http://www.mtbnews.pl/component/option,com_rss/feed,RSS2.0/no_html,1/